# reload jqgrid from window popup IE 8

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, ie8-compatibility-mode

I try to reload my jqgrid after click on the close button in the popup window in IE8. but it gave me several errors and now i tried to reload it in the page itself. meaning that not from the popup window but run a function(resides in main page) upon press the 'close' button in the popup.
i am getting an error - 'window.opener.document' is null or not an object.(in IE8) please find my code below -

popup window function -

```
function closeUserPopup(){

//var x = window.opener.document.getElementById("myjqgrid");
//alert(x);
window.opener.document.callReload(); 
window.close();
```

}

function in the parent page to reload jqgrid-

```
function callReload(){
jq("#mygrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

}

is there any way to reload the parent page jqgrid from the popup window ? ?( before it get closed) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `window.opener.document` but `window.opener`
Try to check if the opener is still valid before.
I usually do something like this:

```
if ( window.opener != null)
   window.opener.callReload();
window.close();
```

A little suggestion.
I've given up with popups like these cause they're hard to manage.
I tend to use a [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) so I can manage everything on the same page.

**UPDATE**

If you're using `window.showModalDialog();` things are even more simple.
Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenDialog(userPopupUrl)
    {
        alert("starting!");
        var vReturnValue = window.showModalDialog(userPopupUrl,"dialogWidth:450px;dialogHeight:100­px;center:yes;resizable:no;status:no;help:no;");
        alert("I am here!");
        // You can refresh whatever you want here!!!!
    }
</script>
```

Since you're creating a dialog the client-script process stops until you close the popup window. At that point, your javascript gets the control back and can fire some other actions.
PS: You can use - as I did - a return value as state [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the response. but since its null the code inside the if block will not get executed. so i can't use that function to reload the grid.will try to shift to jquery ui dialogs. but still it seems to me that there are some problems with IE8 like - opacity of the whole body 'div' tag (when dialog box appears) is not transparent in IE8 unlike in other browsers. :(

Comment: @Sam: how do you open your popup? I've used it loads of times in the past and it has always worked, even with IE8. Try to specify the name of the window like this: window.open ("Page2.html","mywindow"); it must work. As for IE8, well, what do you expect; it scores 20/100 with the acid test http://acid3.acidtests.org/

Comment: i am opening a model dialog box like below - 'window.showModalDialog(userPopupUrl,options,"dialogWidth:450px;dialogHeight:100px;center:yes;resizable:no;status:no;help:no;");'

Comment: @Sam: I've updated my answer with some more infos. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Leftyx. it works. but earlier i tried it based on returnvalue. i got it as 'undefined'. since here we ignore the returnvalue from the popup it works fine for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not best practice, but:

```
(function () {
    var parentLocation = window.opener.location;
    window.opener.location = parentLocation;
})();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. but i am little unclear about that code because i need to reload my jqgrid when popup is closing. it seems to me that above code will refresh my whole page.can you please explain it? thanks again.